# overwriting tag Name on azure resourcegroup with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Below is the azure resource

```bsh
PS C:\Windows\System32> Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName paniRG


Name              : paniavset123
ResourceGroupName : paniRG
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets
Location          : eastus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/8987b447-d083-481e-9c0f-f2b73a15b18b/resourceGroups/paniRG/providers/Microsoft.C
                    ompute/availabilitySets/paniavset123
Tags              : 
                    Name            Value 
                    ==============  ======
                    CostCenter      ABCDEG
                    Owner           john  
                    classification  Public
```

From the above output I want to  replace Tag Name "classification" with "Classification" and "Public" with "Accounts".

I am following the below procedure to do that.

```bsh
PS C:\Windows\System32> $tags=@{"Classification"="Accounts"}

PS C:\Windows\System32> $s=Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName paniRG

PS C:\Windows\System32> Update-AzTag -ResourceId $s.ResourceId -Tag $tags -Operation Merge


Id         : /subscriptions/8987b447-d083-481e-9c0f-f2b73a15b18b/resourceGroups/paniRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/
             paniavset123/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default
Name       : default
Type       : Microsoft.Resources/tags
Properties : 
             Name            Value   
             ==============  ========
             CostCenter      ABCDEG  
             Owner           john    
             classification  Accounts
```

When I use `update-aztag` command Tag Value is changing  but Name its still showing as "classification".

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `classification` tag from the hash table resource `Tags`, then add a new `Classification` tag with the new `Account` value. You can then modify the newly updated hashtable with [`Set-AzResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azresource?view=azps-4.7.0).

```bsh
$resource = Get-AzResource -Name "RESOURCE NAME" -ResourceGroupName "RESOURCE GROUP NAME"

# Get the tags
$tags = $resource.Tags

# Check if hashtable has classification key
if ($tags.ContainsKey("classification")) {

    # Remove classification key if it exists
    $tags.Remove("classification")
}

# Create Classification tag with Accounts value
$tags.Classification = "Accounts"

# Update resource with new tags
$resource | Set-AzResource -Tag $tags -Force
```

If you want to use [`Update-AzTag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-4.7.0), you will need to use a `Replace` operation:

```bsh
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $s.Id -Tag $tags -Operation Replace
```

The `Merge` operation will update the value, but not the key name.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-Operation Replace` not `-Operation Merge`

```
Update-AzTag -ResourceId $s.ResourceId -Tag $mergedTags -Operation Replace
```

Comment: It is overwriting the tags if i user replace options
PS C:\Windows\system32> Update-AzTag -ResourceId $x.ResourceId -Tag $Tags -Operation Replace
Id         : /subscriptions/8987b447-d083-481e-9c0f-f2b73a15b18b/resourceGroups/paniRG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/paniavset
             123/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default
Name       : default
Type       : Microsoft.Resources/tags
Properties : 
             Name            Value   
             ==============  ========
             Classification  Accounts

Comment: yes, isn't it you wanted? or your want to do something different?

Comment: Name            Value   
             ==============  ========
             CostCenter      ABCDEG  
             Owner           john    
             classification  Accounts


I Want CostCenter and Owner Names in the list at the sametime i want "classification" should be changed to "Classification"